# How to implement nested condition in Sitecore search Query Token?

Tags: sxa, content-search

Refereeing this nice post https://ggullentops.blogspot.com/2019/01/extending-sxa-search-query-tokens.html

Above approach works well with simple conditions which generate the below SOLR query 
e.g. condition 1(must) And Condition 2(must) **OR Condition 3(Default) OR Condition 4(Default)**

However, I want something like below which can be complex:

condition 1(must) And Condition 2(must) **And (Condition 3(Default) OR Condition 4(Default))**

Currently, I'm trying to achieve the above requirement by overriding GetQuery implementation of ISearchService.

Does anybody know a better approach? Please share your thoughts.

**Sitecore:** 9.2

**SXA:** 1.9

Comment: If you want to manipulate the query that is the only way.

Comment: Thanks @DawidRutkowski for the confirmation